# How to custom token response format in Spring security 5.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I use Spring-cloud  Greenwich.RELEASE and import :
spring-cloud-starter-security 
spring-cloud-starter-oauth2

when I login success response this :

```
{ 
    "access_token":"950a7cc9-5a8a-42c9-a693-40e817b1a4b0", 
    "token_type":"bearer", 
    "refresh_token":"773a0fcd-6023-45f8-8848-e141296cb3cb", 
    "expires_in":27036, 
    "scope":"select" 
}
```

I want to change this:

```
{
    "code" : 200,
    "data" : { 
    "access_token":"950a7cc9-5a8a-42c9-a693-40e817b1a4b0", 
    "token_type":"bearer", 
    "refresh_token":"773a0fcd-6023-45f8-8848-e141296cb3cb", 
    "expires_in":27036, 
    "scope":"select" 
    }
}
```

How to do ?

Comment: If you really want to do that you have to extend `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. That is an OAuth format. It doesn't make sense to use a framework which is based off some standard and then ask how to change the standard.